# Character replacement and split for new columns in CSV dataframe using Python, sklearn, Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

Currently, I am trying to turn column 6 from a date format that is using backslash (ex. 2/4/09) to dash and no 0 (2-4-9). Furthermore, I want to take each value and give it its own colum (as seen in desired output). I tried researching and implementing some solutions but I can't seem to figure it out. I am still trying to figure out how to replace the characters/remove characters (as seen below). I'm pretty new to working with dataframes with Python. Any tips or help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import ensemble
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')

df[6].replace(['\/'],['-'],regex=True, regex=True)
df[6].replace('0','',regex=True,inplace=True)
```

Error:

```
classifier_v1.4.py:18: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  df.dropna(inplace=True, subset=['Name', 'TRY', 'LOC', 'OUTPUT', 'TYPE_A', 'SIGNAL', 'A-B', 'SPOT'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/namel/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2646, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 111, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1618, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1626, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 5

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file.py", line 20, in <module>
    df[5].replace(['\/'],['-'],regex=True)
  File "/Users/name/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2800, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "/Users/name/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2648, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 111, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1618, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1626, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 5
```

Current dataframe:

```
         0    1    2        3          4       5        6     7  
0     Name  TRY  LOC   OUTPUT     TYPE_A   SIGNAL     A-B  SPOT 
1    inc 1    2   20   TYPE-1    TORPEDO   ULTRA   2/4/09   -21
2    inc 2    3   16   TYPE-2    TORPEDO     ILH   2/4/09   -14
3    inc 3    2   20  BLACK47    TORPEDO    LION   2/4/09    49
4    inc 4    3   12   TYPE-2  CENTRALPA    LION   2/4/09    25
5    inc 5    3   10   TYPE-2      THREE    LION   2/4/09   -21
6    inc 6    2   20   TYPE-2        ATF    LION   2/4/09   -48
7    inc 7    4    2  NIVEA-1        ATF    LION   7/3/03   -23
8    inc 8    3   16  NIVEA-1        ATF    LION   7/3/03    18
9    inc 9    3   18  BLENDER  CENTRALPA    LION   7/3/03    48
10   inc 10   4   20    DELCO        ATF    LION   7/3/03   -26
11   inc 11   3   20    VE248        ATF    LION   7/3/03    44
12   inc 12   1   20   SILVER  CENTRALPA    LION   5/9/02   -35
13   inc 13   2   20  CALVIN3     SEVENX    LION   5/9/02   -20
14   inc 14   3   14  DECK-BT  CENTRALPA    LION   5/9/02   -38
15   inc 15   4    4  10-LEVI    BERWYEN     OWL   5/9/02   -29
16   inc 16   4   14   TYPE-2        ATF     NOV   5/9/02   -31
17   inc 17   4   10     NYNY    TORPEDO     NOV   5/9/02    21
18   inc 18   2   20  NIVEA-1  CENTRALPA     NOV   1/7/06    45
19   inc 19   3   27   FMRA97    TORPEDO     NOV   1/7/06   -26
20   inc 20   4   18   SILVER        ATF     NOV   1/7/06   -46
```

Desired output:

```
         0    1    2        3          4       5       6   7   8   9     7   
0     Name  TRY  LOC   OUTPUT     TYPE_A   SIGNAL    A-B  D1  D2  D3  SPOT 
1    inc 1    2   20   TYPE-1    TORPEDO   ULTRA   2-4-9   2   4   9   -21
2    inc 2    3   16   TYPE-2    TORPEDO     ILH   2-4-9   2   4   9   -14
3    inc 3    2   20  BLACK47    TORPEDO    LION   2-4-9   2   4   9    49
4    inc 4    3   12   TYPE-2  CENTRALPA    LION   2-4-9   2   4   9    25
5    inc 5    3   10   TYPE-2      THREE    LION   2-4-9   2   4   9   -21
6    inc 6    2   20   TYPE-2        ATF    LION   2-4-9   2   4   9   -48
7    inc 7    4    2  NIVEA-1        ATF    LION   7-3-3   7   3   3   -23
8    inc 8    3   16  NIVEA-1        ATF    LION   7-3-3   7   3   3    18
9    inc 9    3   18  BLENDER  CENTRALPA    LION   7-3-3   7   3   3    48
10   inc 10   4   20    DELCO        ATF    LION   7-3-3   7   3   3   -26
11   inc 11   3   20    VE248        ATF    LION   7-3-3   7   3   3    44
12   inc 12   1   20   SILVER  CENTRALPA    LION   5-9-2   5   9   2   -35
13   inc 13   2   20  CALVIN3     SEVENX    LION   5-9-2   5   9   2   -20
14   inc 14   3   14  DECK-BT  CENTRALPA    LION   5-9-2   5   9   2   -38
15   inc 15   4    4  10-LEVI    BERWYEN     OWL   5-9-2   5   9   2   -29
16   inc 16   4   14   TYPE-2        ATF     NOV   5-9-2   5   9   2   -31
17   inc 17   4   10     NYNY    TORPEDO     NOV   5-9-2   5   9   2    21
18   inc 18   2   20  NIVEA-1  CENTRALPA     NOV   1-7-6   1   7   6    45
19   inc 19   3   27   FMRA97    TORPEDO     NOV   1-7-6   1   7   6   -26
20   inc 20   4   18   SILVER        ATF     NOV   1-7-6   1   7   6   -46
```

Comment: maybe this would help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54738131/why-is-str-replace-on-the-index-giving-keyerror

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a more efficient way to do this, but the code below will achieve what you want.

```
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import ensemble
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')

# insert columns
df.insert(7, 'D1', '')
df.insert(8, 'D2', '')
df.insert(9, 'D3', '')

# replace
df['A-B'] = df['A-B'].str.replace('/', '-')
df['A-B'] = df['A-B'].str.replace('0', '')

# update new columns values
df['D1'] = df.apply(lambda x: str(x['A-B']).split('-')[0], axis=1)
df['D2'] = df.apply(lambda x: str(x['A-B']).split('-')[1], axis=1)
df['D3'] = df.apply(lambda x: str(x['A-B']).split('-')[2], axis=1)

print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are processing dates you could load the dates as `DateTime` upon reading the csv and process them further. It does acquire additional processing due to the uncommon formatting of the year (without zero padding) you wish to achieve:

```
dateparser = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, '%d/%m/%y')
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', parse_dates=['A-B'], date_parser=dateparser)
df['D1'] = df['A-B'].dt.day
df['D2'] = df['A-B'].dt.month
df['D3'] = df['A-B'].dt.year
df['D3'] = df.apply(lambda row: int(str(row['A-B'].year)[3:]), axis=1)
df['A-B'] = df['A-B'].apply(lambda x: str(x.strftime('%d-%m-%y')).replace("0", ""))
```

Output:

|  | Name | TRY | LOC | OUTPUT | TYPE_A | SIGNAL | A-B | SPOT | D1 | D2 | D3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | inc1 | 2 | 20 | TYPE-1 | TORPEDO | ULTRA | 2-4-9 | -21 | 2 | 4 | 9 |
| 1 | inc2 | 3 | 16 | TYPE-2 | TORPEDO | ILH | 2-4-9 | -14 | 2 | 4 | 9 |
| 2 | inc3 | 2 | 20 | BLACK47 | TORPEDO | LION | 2-4-9 | 49 | 2 | 4 | 9 |
| 3 | inc4 | 3 | 12 | TYPE-2 | CENTRALPA | LION | 2-4-9 | 25 | 2 | 4 | 9 |
| 4 | inc5 | 3 | 10 | TYPE-2 | THREE | LION | 2-4-9 | -21 | 2 | 4 | 9 |

Answer (score 0):

`KeyError: 5` means that key 5 doesn't exist. In this case, it is no integer but a string, so you need to use quotes.

Another (and probably more practical) approach is to drop the first row and use row 1 for column headers.

There is no problem with your `.replace` using lists for both original and new values. There are several alternative ways, two of them are shown hereunder.

Using `split` as shown below, you can add the three new columns at the same same.

```
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import ensemble
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('/Users/ciit2/downloads/test.csv', header=1)
df['A-B'].replace({'/': '-'}, regex=True, inplace=True)
df['A-B'].replace('0', '', regex=True, inplace=True)
df[['D1', 'D2', 'D3']] = pd.DataFrame(df['A-B'].str.split('-').tolist())
df
```